# How do i perform a distinct statement in azure applications insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have a query that pulls a list of user engements of the form:
Date, user name, campaign_id,

There is uniqueness in the campaign_id in a sense that a user clicks only once per day per campaign_id (campaign id cant be logged twice for the same user within a day)

My question is how do I pull a list of unique active users per month?  A user can be logged more than once for different campaigns and different days.

```
customEvents 
| extend rTimeStamp = todatetime(customDimensions.timeStamp), 
         username = tolower(tostring(customDimensions.username)), 
         event = name, item_uid = tostring(customDimensions.itemId) 
| extend rTimeStamp = todatetime(substring(tostring(rTimeStamp), 0, 10)) 
| where event == 'click' 
| project rTimeStamp, username, event, item_uid
| summarize arg_min(rTimeStamp, *) by item_uid, username 
| summarize click_count = countif(event == 'click') by rTimeStamp, username, item_uid 
| order by rTimeStamp
```

Comment: You mean using Application Insights Analytics? If so, can you post the query you have so far?

Comment: Yes. Here the query that gives me the results I've stated before:

customEvents
| extend rTimeStamp = todatetime(customDimensions.timeStamp), username = tolower(tostring(customDimensions.username)), 
event = name, item_uid = tostring(customDimensions.itemId)
| extend rTimeStamp = todatetime(substring(tostring(rTimeStamp), 0, 10))
| where event == 'click'
| project rTimeStamp, username, event, item_uid
| summarize arg_min(rTimeStamp, *) by item_uid, username
| summarize click_count = countif(event == 'click') by rTimeStamp, username, item_uid
| order by rTimeStamp

Comment: Thanks. But please, next time edit the question to add extra details. It makes it better readable :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the "[distinct](https://docs.loganalytics.io/docs/Language-Reference/Tabular-operators/distinct-operator)" operator:

```
... 
| distinct username
```

If you'd like a list of distinct users per month, also possible with summarize:

```
...
| summarize by username, bin(rTimeStamp, 30d)
```