# Azure app insights user counts query questions

Tags: azure

I am a beginner and having a hard time grasping what I need to do to get the data below using log analytics. Can you please help?

I have implemented app insights and installed the angular plugin to the code. I am seeing data in log analytics.
-What is the best way to get the count of a user and how many times they logged in by day for(for 30 days for example). Is it to query against the **pageViews** table?
-Another use case is if they logged in 10 times a day I want all the counts(10) by user id and similar data for all 30 days.

- also how would i query against it?  Is there a place where I can type in the "userid" and then populate the data?
  also what would be a query i can use to count the number of *unique* users on a date or date range.

Sorry this is a lot to ask. Any help or assitance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**What is the best way to get the count of a user and how many times they logged in by day?**
Use the `Users tool` in `Application Insights`.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/usage-segmentation

**Another use case is if they logged in 10 times a day I want all the counts(10) by user id and similar data for all 30 days.**
I am a bit unsure here. To my knowledge this is not possible out of the box. You could log a custom event with the user´s ID every time a user logs in. Then you can use the `Events tool` afterwards to count these events.

**also how would i query against it? Is there a place where I can type in the "userid" and then populate the data?**
Use the `filter` option in `Users tool`.

also what would be a query i can use to count the number of unique users on a date or date range.
You can use the `dcount()` function in KQL.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/dcount-aggfunction
The use it together with the `summarize` to group by date or date range. See more here:
[How do i perform a distinct statement in azure applications insights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50591017/how-do-i-perform-a-distinct-statement-in-azure-applications-insights)